# How to edit road badges in Skobbler?

Tags: styling, skmaps, scoutstyleeditor

I cannot find any "badge" feature in the StyleEditor at any level and I would like to change the color of the road badges.

Answer (score 3):

The link between the badge icon from the map and the used badge image is found the *.json* file.

All the badge icons are defined in the **highway_signs.png** image file found in **"Common"** folder, bundled together as sprites:

```
"badges" : 
    [

        {
            "columns" : 2,
            "filename" : "highway_signs.png",
            "id" : 59,
            "rows" : 8,
            "textcolor" : "FFFFFF"
        }
    ],
```

and then each badges uses a different "icon" from a different position

```
"text" : 
            {
                "badge" : 
                {
                    "badgeid" : 59,
                    "badgetype" : "#0#1",
                    "color" : "FFFFFF",
                    "fontid" : [ 3, 3, 3, 3 ],
                    "fontid3d" : [ 7, 7, 7, 6 ],
                    "format" : "#1",
                    "horizontal" : true,
                    "outlinecolor" : "ffffffff",
                    "position" : "path",
                    "spacing" : 400
                }
            }
```

the key being the `"badgetype" : "#0#1"` line that indicates that we'll use the image from the first row (0 index based rows), second column (0 index based columns).

If you want to modify the badge icons, modify the highway_signs.png file.
If you want to remove the badges from the map - remove the "badge" elements from road element definitions.